# Plot smooth graph from user defined points

Tags: r, graph

I would like to draw a smooth graph, with just specifying some points. An example would be the following graph:

[[desired graph]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm8QO.png)

I would like to draw it with the following points:

```
x <- c(7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18)
y <- c(0.05, 0.95, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3, 0.95, 0.2)
```

How can I estimate the missing points, so that it results in a smooth graph that looks similar to the figure?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is with a spline function.  That will give you not only the curve, but a function to estimate y for any x.

```
SF = splinefun(x,y)
curve(SF, xlim=c(7,18))
points(x,y, pch=16, col="red")
```

[image: Spline function]

Answer (score 0):

For 10 data points you can add a 9th order polynomial to obtain something like it. This can be fit directly to your data with `geom_smooth` from ggplot2 in the following way

```
x <- c(7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18)
y <- c(0.05, 0.95, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3, 0.95, 0.2)

df <- data.frame(x,y)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="lm",
          formula=y ~ poly(x, 9, raw=TRUE),
          colour="red")
```